# React testing library not displaying input onChange prop in snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

I have a simple snapshot test with RTL and Jest, any other prop I use beside `type` and `placeholder` I don't see it in the resulting snapshot. This is my input component: (I'm using styled component)

```
const TextField = ({ className, placeholder, onChange, type }) => {
  return (
    <Styled>
      <Styled.input
        type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        className={className}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </Styled>
  );
};
```

This is my test:

```
  it('shall render correctly', () => {
    const { asFragment  } = render(
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <TextField placeholder="Ramdom text" type="search" onChange={jest.fn()} />
      </ThemeProvider>,
    );

    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

The resulting snapshot:

```
exports[`TextField component shall render correctly 1`] = `
<DocumentFragment>
  .c0 {
  position: relative;
}

.c1 {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: solid 0px;
  border-radius: 10em;
  background: #f4f5f8;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px NaNpx;
  font: 400 1.6rem/normal 'Open Sans','Helvetica','Arial',sans-serif;
  -webkit-letter-spacing: normal;
  -moz-letter-spacing: normal;
  -ms-letter-spacing: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
}

<label
    class="c0"
  >
    <input
      class="c1"
      placeholder="Ramdom text"
      type="search"
    />
  </label>
</DocumentFragment>
`;
```

As you can see there's no onChange prop in the input props.

Answer (score -1):

`onChange` in your JSX is event handler provided by React and it's not shown in the actual DOM, which RTL renders.

Comment: Not only onChange even a prop "blabla" don't get displayed, anything other than the official HTLM input attributes don't get displayed